# Find all pixels on a line in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, line, pixel

To get right to it: Say I've got two specific pixels a & b, as well as a list of random others. I now want to check all pixels in that list if they are on the line which passes through a & b (but which is NOT restricted to have a & b as endpoints!)
I looked at Bresenham's line algorithm, but that seems to only find the points between a & b?
I've also had a look at linear equations in general but I'm kind of stuck on how to properly discretize the continuous line into pixels...

(I'm trying to implement a random sampling algorithm in java, which tries to find the line with the most pixels on it, if that matters).

Thanks a lot for any help with this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suggest that you compute the **distance between the point and the line**.

If you use one pixel as unit of measurement (which you will if you work in a pixel coordinate system), you can simply check if the distance from the point to the line is < 1.

Here's how to compute the distance between a point and a line:

- [Minimum Distance between a Point and a Line](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/)
- [Wolfram: Point-Line Distance--2-Dimensional](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html)

Comment: Bresenham's line algorithm is much faster and could be easily adapted to the case.

Answer (score 0):

You could search not between a and b, but between the points that are on the same line, but out of the borders of image. You can get them simply putting vector (b-a) necessary amount of times to the a side and to the b side. And the use your Bresenham's line algorithm.

As for more concrete answers, define the question better, please.  Do you consider pixels as points or squares or circles?  What is "pixel is on the line" in your terms? What width has your line? You are looking for the line with max number of pixels on the cm length or in the rectangle borders? Among what lines do you search?

Comment: Bressenhams line algorithm finds "all pixels forming a line". That algorithm must by definition be linear in *the length* of the line. Have I understood you correct?

Comment: AFAIK and IMHO, it is the algorithm, by wich 2d graphic function draw a line from point to point. It should be the fastest one.

Comment: I believe you completely misunderstood the OPs question. He has a set of points, and he wants to find out which of those points are on the line. For that he obviously don't have to look at *every single point along the line*. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Hmm. Yes. Sorry. I've only guessed. But my answer remains valid. The questioner knows and would like to use some algorythm. (Bressenhams' one). But doesn't know how to use it on the parts of the line out of the segment given. I told him how to do it. Any other algorithm will take him more time, because this one he already has coded, as I understood.